# iOS 12 beta 9, Xcode 10.0 beta 6 Unable to build the WebdriverAgent getting error - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios-ui-automation, ios12

Getting this error while building
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"OBJC_CLASS$XCElementSnapshot", referenced from:
l_OBJC$CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot$FBIsVisible in XCUIElement+FBIsVisible.o
l_OBJC$CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot$FBUID in XCUIElement+FBUID.o
l_OBJC$CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot$WebDriverAttributes in XCUIElement+FBWebDriverAttributes.o
objc-class-ref in XCUIElement+FBWebDriverAttributes.o
l_OBJC$CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot$FBAccessibility in XCUIElement+FBAccessibility.o
l_OBJC$CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot$FBScrolling in XCUIElement+FBScrolling.o
l_OBJC$CATEGORY_XCElementSnapshot$_FBHitPoint in XCElementSnapshot+FBHitPoint.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after taking latest code.

Comment: is the above issue fixed after taking latest webdriverAgent code?

Comment: Yes.Anyway you need to update everything.Update appium to 1.9.1